# How to get value and select text in select with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following select (in jade):

```
select(ng-model="note.shop1", ng-change="selectShop()", ng-disabled="allShops" ng-show="positionAvailable")
   option(ng-repeat="shop in nearbyShops" value="{{shop._id}}")
     {{shop.name}} ({{shop.contact_address}} {{shop.contact_housenr}}, {{shop.contact_city}})
   option(value="otherShop") My store isn't listed.
```

Selectshop() in my controller:

```
$scope.selectShop = function(){

        if($scope.note.shop1 == "otherShop"){
            $scope.allShops = true;
        }
}
```

I want to store the selected ID, so I can save it, but I want to show the `{{shop.name}}` to the user when he selected a shop.
How can I do that?

So, I want selected `{{shop._id}}`, and select `{{shop.name}}` saved.

Comment: Can you show me your `selectShop()` method? and you want to store both store id and shop name right?

Comment: Added some code to my post. I forget something and yes, I want to store both.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to remove the `._id` from the value to pass the object in your `ng-change` method. Try this.

```
select(ng-model="note.shop1", ng-change="selectShop(note.shop1)", ng-disabled="allShops" ng-show="positionAvailable")
   option(ng-repeat="shop in nearbyShops" value="{{shop}}")
     {{shop.name}} ({{shop.contact_address}} {{shop.contact_housenr}}, {{shop.contact_city}})
```

and In your `selectShop` method. get them by

```
$scope.selectShop = function(selectedShop){
    console.log(selectedShop._id, selectedShop.name);
        if($scope.note.shop1 == "otherShop"){
            $scope.allShops = true;
        }
}
```

I've made a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bsgq553g/) to demonstrate.

Hope it helps.

Comment: When i do console.log(shop) in selectShop, I get the whole shop, but when I do console.log(shop.name) I get 'undefined'. What is going wrong? :)

Comment: Try `console.log(selectedShop._id, selectedShop.name);` in `selectShop()` method

Comment: Hmm, 2 'undefined's'

Comment: Have you tried the above markup for select too? 
`select(ng-model="note.shop1", ng-change="selectShop(note.shop1)", ng-disabled="allShops" ng-show="positionAvailable")
   option(ng-repeat="shop in nearbyShops" value="{{shop}}")
     {{shop.name}} ({{shop.contact_address}} {{shop.contact_housenr}}, {{shop.contact_city}})`

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest and HTML version for your problem.

```
 <select ng-model="selectedShop._id" ng-options="selectedShop._ID as selectedShop.name for selectedShop in nearbyShops" 
   ng-change=selectShop(selectedShop,{{selectedShop._id}})></select>
```

and your function will be

```
$scope.selectShop = function(shop){
// your selected shop id will be $scope.shop._id

}
```